# Convert function arguments to str

Tags: python, biopython

I wrote a function and call it as below:

```
from lib import base_frequency

base_frequency("AB610939-AB610950.gb", "genbank")
#This calls the function that uses a BioPython code.
```

How could I pass the function arguments as below?

```
base_frequency(AB610939-AB610950.gb, genbank)
```

Note that quotes are missing. Should I do this? Is there a recommended nomenclature in Python when function argument is sting?

I thought this required me to convert filename and record format to a string inside the function. That is:

```
AB610939-AB610950.gb to "AB610939-AB610950.gb"
genbank to "genbank"
```

I have tried `str(AB610939-AB610950.gb)` inside the function but it did not do the job.

Comment: You need to add the quotes. Why do you need to do this anyway?

Comment: I am trying to learn Python, and a question had in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this without quotes, or else Python will interpret it as an expression. Take the first argument for example,

```
AB610939-AB610950.gb
```

Python will read this as a subtraction operation between two variables, `AB610939` and the `gb` property of `AB610950`, not a sequence of characters. The only way to stop this is to surround it in quotation marks to make it string literal.

Comment: That is useful information for me.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a recommended nomenclature in Python when function argument is string?

Yes.

Enclose a string literal "within quotes".

Here is a pair of valid examples of doing that:

> ```
> base_frequency("AB610939-AB610950.gb", "genbank")
> ```

That produces a pair of `str` values,
pushes them onto the stack,
and calls the base_frequency function.

If e.g. the 2nd arg was an unquoted `genbank`,
that would mean something entirely different.
It would mean "please look up the value of
the variable named `genbank` and pass its
value to the function."

If you ask for a variable that does not exist,
the result will be a NameError.